# What is the purpose of "io.popen" function?

Tags: lua

I'm using an iOS application called AutoTouch. This app uses scripts based on Lua language. The developers of AutoTouch included the possibilty to call io.popen function, however I can't find any "understandable" examples of its use.

For example, I found this description:

> ```
> io.popen(prog[,mode])
> ```
>
> Starts program prog in a separated process   and returns a file handle that you can use to read data from this program (if mode is "r", the default) or to write data to this program (if mode is "w").

Does it mean that with the help of this function it's possible to use any command or application that is accessible through regular iOS terminal (on jailbroken system)?

The reason I'm asking is because I would like to copy a screenshot that is kept in AutoTouch default folder to the Camera Roll folder. I thought I could somehow use the commands of Terminal to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The leading **p** of `popen` means **pipe**. This function is a thin wrapper around the [C function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html) and starts a process by command `prog`, additionally building a pipe between the host (your program) and the spawned process with the direction by `mode`. This pipe allows communication, so you can read what the process wrote to standard output so far or the process waits for standard input and you can serve with this. It's often used to get output of popular Unix programs which functionality is a pain to write as source code.

For a file copy, using `popen` is a dirty way. Sadly there's no `os.copy` function, so you have to use `io.*` functions (open in binary mode for binary files like images).

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation!